# Grouping strings together based on common first words

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of different items, some of these have a size and colour description at the end. E.g. Men's Football Jacket - L / Black.

I'd like to be able to group all Men's Football Jacket products regardless of size or colour.

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════╤══════╗
║ Item                              │ Sold ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════╪══════╣
║ Men's Football Jacket - L / Blue  │ 5    ║
╟───────────────────────────────────┼──────╢
║ Men's Football Jacket - M / Black │ 3    ║
╟───────────────────────────────────┼──────╢
║ Women's Socks - S                 │ 8    ║
╟───────────────────────────────────┼──────╢
║ Women's Socks - L                 │ 10   ║
╟───────────────────────────────────┼──────╢
║ Gloves                            │ 12   ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════╧══════╝

Output:
╔═══════════════════════╤══════╗
║ Item                  │ Sold ║
╠═══════════════════════╪══════╣
║ Men's Football Jacket │ 8    ║
╟───────────────────────┼──────╢
║ Women's Socks         │ 18   ║
╟───────────────────────┼──────╢
║ Gloves                │ 12   ║
╚═══════════════════════╧══════╝
```

As you can see from the example, some items only have size in the string, other have neither size nor colour specified.

I'm using MySQL if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is it consistent that you need to cut everything off after `-` or if `-` is not present, then take the entire value?

Comment: There are some strings which have the text (Pre-order) but I guess I can replace with "(Pre Order)", then somehow cut out everything after the "-" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are always separated by space-hyphen-space, then just use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(item, ' - ', 1) as item,
       sum(sold)
from t
group by substring_index(item, ' - ', 1) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group by the values of Item up to the 1st `-`, use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to extract that part of the string:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Item, '-', 1) Item, 
       SUM(Sold) Sold
FROM tablename
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(Item, '-', 1)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=705e0ce775ba5e554087eac1955c8c4b).
Results:

```
> Item                  | Sold
> :-------------------- | ---:
> Gloves                |   12
> Men's Football Jacket |    8
> Women's Socks         |   18
```

Comment: Are you doing the Concat function to avoid errors in strings which don't contain a '-'?

Comment: @user14461410 yes, that's what I did, but in fact substring_index does not need it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index I edited.